# Set the "Ultimate Performance" power plan on Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11

On Windows 11, how can you set the "Ultimate Performance" power setting?

I've tried:

```
> powercfg -s e9a42b02-d5df-448d-aa00-03f14749eb61
Attempted to write to unsupported setting
```

ps.
I'm using a Surface Book 2 laptop

[image]

Comment: Simplest solution is to upgrade to *Windows 11 Professional for Workstations*

Answer (score 1):

> Attempted to write to unsupported setting

Not all power plans are available in all computers. Please see below and the tutorial. This depends on the particular computer and may depend on the operating system in use.

Try creating a Custom Power plan (Control Panel, Power).  Power plans just control how much battery is used.  That does not speed up your PC beyond its normal capabilities.

Note in the article that not all power plans are available in all computers.  That is likely what is happening to you.

Here is a good tutorial for Power Plans.

To list all your plans:

> powercfg /Q >"%UserProfile%\Desktop\PowerPlanSettings.txt"

[Power Plan descriptions](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/124566-view-all-power-plan-settings-text-file-windows.html)

> Windows 10 provides the following default plans: Balanced - Offers
> full performance when you need it and saves power when you don't. This
> is the best power plan for most people. Power saver - Saves power by
> reducing PC performance and screen brightness. If you're using a
> laptop, this plan can help you get the most from a single battery
> charge. High performance - Maximizes screen brightness and might
> increase PC performance. This plan uses a lot more energy, so your
> laptop battery won't last as long between charges. Ultimate
> Performance - Only available starting with Windows 10 build 17083.
> Provides ultimate performance on higher end PCs. Custom power plan -
> These are only available if either your PC manufacturer (OEM) provided
> additional power plans, and/or you create a custom power plan. These
> are available to all users.
>
> Normally, you could view all current settings of a power plan in Power
> Options. If you like, you could also output these settings to a text
> file. This can make it easier to share or show the power plan
> settings.
>
> If you like, you can choose to include all hidden settings of a power
> plan, but these settings are hidden by default in Power Options since
> they usually do not apply to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set it to the active plan because the plan doesn't exist yet on the system.  Or, to put it a better way it hasn't been loaded by default.

You first need to instantiate the plan with the following:

```
powercfg -duplicatescheme e9a42b02-d5df-448d-aa00-03f14749eb61
```

Then you can list it and set it.  To restore all "default" power plans to Windows 11 (22H2 tested) do the following:

```
# Restore all power schemes on Windows 11 (22H2)
# Restore Balanced
powercfg -restoredefaultschemes
# Restore High performance
powercfg -duplicatescheme 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c
# Restore Power saver
powercfg -duplicatescheme a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a
# Restore Ultimate Performance
powercfg -duplicatescheme e9a42b02-d5df-448d-aa00-03f14749eb61
```

***WARNING*** - this will remove all your existing power settings.  You can export/import custom settings with the powercfg tool.  See "/?" for options.